# C# Increment Alphabet character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to increment the first character of a string to the next letter in the Alphabet.

I have found this:

```
string str_A1 = "A1";
string str_B;

str_B= str[0]++;
```

Here `str_B` should be "B" but I get an error saying:

> Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: This question new some changes. What is str[]? It looks like an array, but you dont explain what is the content. And you should not do like this str[0]++. Increase the index if you want or the value you retrieve from str[0]

Comment: The code doesn't even compile, and since when can you increment a letter? You at least need some sort of reference to what comes after "A".

Comment: `ToCharArray()`, `[0]++`, `new string(...)`.

Comment: The question has been answered, but here is why your code does not compile:

`String` is immutable. This means that you cannot modify the string. All the operations on a string only returns a copy of the string (replace, remove, substring, etc). Because of that, the indexor (`[]` op) only define a `get`.

The `++` operator return the value of the associated variable, then increment the value and affect the new value to the variable.

Since the `++` affect the value of the increment to the associated variable, it tries to call the set on the indexor. But as I said, there is no such `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the value of the first character of str_A1, which is what the ++ operator is doing. Do this instead:

```
str_B = ((char)(str[0] + 1)).ToString();
```

Comment: This would give him the integer answer.

Comment: Have you tried this solution??

Comment: Oh you're right. Let me fix it.

Comment: Ok looks like your edited solution works

Comment: @RewForeN Try the new edit. It was my mistake for fogetting to convert the int back into a char.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like:

```
string str_A1 = "A1";
string str_B = (char)(str_A1[0] + 1) + str_A1.Remove(0, 1);
```

Comment: More complete answer as it considers the full string, not just the first character.